# Kafka quick start with problems

Tags: apache-kafka

I am following the instructions for quick start Kafka, according to [Apache Kafka Quickstart](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart)

The zookeeper and Kafka server started properly, but the messages are either not sent or received.

```
C:\Java2017\kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0\kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0\bin\windows>kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
testing...
```

```
C:\Java2017\kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0\kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0\bin\windows>kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning
```

Comment: What messages are you receiving?

Answer (score 0):

You might have done the right thing in practice, but the producer command you specified above should be like this:

```
C:\Java2017\kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0\kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0\bin\windows>kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
>testing...
>[Ctrl-C]
C:\Java2017\kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0\kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0\bin\windows>
```

Nothing will be produced if you run it like this:

```
C:\Java2017\kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0\kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0\bin\windows>kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test testing...
```